# Unlink not deleting file

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to delete a file that is uploaded to my server after the file is successfully sent to Box via API. However, `unlink` isn't deleting the file. Below is relevant part of my code:

```
$cur_time = time();
$apikey= $_SESSION["api_key"];
$list_id = $_POST['list_id'];
$justfile= "list-".$list_id."-".$cur_time.".csv";
$filename = "data/list-".$list_id."-".$cur_time.".csv";
$final_file = file_put_contents($filename, $csvOutput);
$cur_time = time();

$headr[] = 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; 
  $target_url = 'https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content';
  $file_name_with_full_path = realpath($final_file);
 $json = json_encode(array(
                                'name' => $list_id."-".$cur_time.".csv", 
                                'parent' => array('id' => 4224475591)
                            ));
        $fields = array(
                      'attributes' => $json,
                      'file'=>'@'.$filename
                  );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  $result = json_decode( curl_exec($ch));
  curl_close ($ch);
  $my_resp = $result->total_count; //if 1, then upload to Box was successful
  if ($my_resp ==1){
    echo("success");
    unlink($justfile);
  }
  else{
    echo("problem");
    unlink($justfile);
  }
```

If I do `var_dump($justfile)`, I get a string that perfectly matches the file that is supposed to be deleted and now sits on my server.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What warnings do you receive? `unlink` generates an `E_WARNING` on failure.

Comment: Do you have directory permission to remove files? Try it directly removing some *.txt using just `unlink($path_to_txt_file);` and see what you get.

Comment: `.../files/content';` might need a slash here at the end `.../files/content/';` I could be wrong though.

Comment: Do you have directory permission to remove files? Try it directly removing some *.txt using just `unlink($path_to_txt_file);` and see what you get.

Comment: Figured out the issue...didn't include a full path in my `unlink`

Comment: Do you have directory permission to remove files? Try it directly removing some *.txt using just `unlink($path_to_txt_file);` and see what you get.

Comment: *Ah, food for thought* ^ - edit: meant for comment above this.

Comment: Curious though; why use `$justfile`? *For internal use only*?

Comment: @Fred-ii- That was my mistake. I didn't think I needed a path included in the `unlink` so I created the `$justfile` to have the file name, but not the path. Turns out that was what was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. I neglected to include the proper path in my `unlink`. Instead of `unlink($justfile);` I needed `unlink($filename);`, as this contains the full path to the file.